# Zookeeper: how to rename, copy or move a path?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a Zookeeper path `/xxx/yyy/zzz` how can I copy/move it to another path without coding a script? Can I do that with some tool like `zkCli.sh`?

Comment: What do you mean by "without coding a script"? A reliable copy operation requires some transactional control. As far as I know, this can only be achieved through client libraries.

Answer (score 2):

There's no command like rename , you can use `delete` and `create` ,maybe together  with `multi` .